# Ranges with different step size for odd and even steps in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

What is the fastest and the simplest way to generate an array like

`[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, ...]`

in MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the cumulative sum of the vector of steps (in your case it is `[1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...]`). For example:

```
x = cumsum([0, repmat([1 2], 1, 4)])

x = 
    0     1     3     4     6     7     9    10    12
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate matrix with two rows: top row for odd array elements, bottom row for even elements. Than transform matrix into array with reshape.

```
>> a=[0:3:15; 1:3:16]
a =
     0     3     6     9    12    15
     1     4     7    10    13    16
>> a=reshape(a,1,12)
a =
     0     1     3     4     6     7     9    10    12    13    15    16
```

Answer (score 3):

Not one line but will work for either an odd or even number of total elements, and could be expanded if you wanted more than two different steps:

```
a = zeros(1,8);
a(1:2:end) = 0:3:10; 
a(2:2:end) = 1:3:10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and compact way:

```
A = 0:20;
A(3:3:end) = []
```